# Wordpress category filter doesn't filter on sub categories

Tags: php, categories, custom-post-type, wordpress

I have multiple sub categories like

- parent

  - child 1
  - child 2
  - child 3
  - child 4

with custom post types.

What I am trying to reach is on my custom category template :

a list (links ) of all the sub category's with the quantity of custom posts each category contains.

```
<div class="category">
<h3>Category:</h3>
<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'books',
    'orderby' => '_swauteur',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'parent' => '513' 
                 );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<div class="cat"><h2><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "have a look at %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' 
. $category->name.'</a></h2><br /><p>Books: '. $category->count.' </p></div> '; 
 } 
?>
</div>
```

This works as a charm, I get all the categories containing posts!

Then in the loop, all the posts from the 4 child categories

```
    <div class="box">   

     <div class="post-alt blog">

<ul class="article-list article-list--related">
<?php $books = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $books->have_posts() ) : $books->the_post();?>  
<li class="article-list_item  tile post-tile">
 <article class="article-list_article">   
    <section class="article">
      <div class="article_thumb"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');} else { echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/placeholder.png" />';}?></div>
      <div class="article_title"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
          <p>Auteur: <?php echo get_post_meta($id, "_swauteur", true); ?></p>
          <p class="article_pub-date">Publicatie datum:<?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime(get_post_meta($id, "_pubdatum",true)));?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="article_excerpt">
            <p class="article_excerpt_content"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
          <p><a title="<?php _e('Read More'); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">Lees meer</a></p>

        </div>

    </section>
  </article>
</li>             
</ul>

<?php endwhile; ?>          
                </div><!--/post-alt blog-->

    <div class="navigation">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Previous Entries')) ?>   </div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Next Entries &raquo;')) ?></div>
    </div>      

</div> <!--closebox-->  

    </div><!--/col1-->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is also working, I get all the post from all categories !!

But here is my question:

I can't figure out how to make a combination of both, because when I click category link of child 1, no selection is done, I still get all the posts from other sub categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do several different WP_Query's with the restraining arguments to get only those posts you want. You will have to do several loops if you want it to limit them to one sub category.

You might have to make templates for these category pages and put your customized loops in there, or better to avoid repeating code, you make a category.php template in which you check the global `$query` in order to determine which sub category was asked and set the correct `$args` before generating the loop.

**update**:

As you use a custom query, WP returns you the posts specified by your custom query $args. Under normal circumstances WP gets the `$args` based on which url you are showing and query parameters of the url. If you click on you child category link, you will find that it specifies the category in the url. Since you run your own query, WP ignores the page you're on. Well, it doesn't really ignore it, but it puts it's loop in a global variable `$query` whereas you are showing the loop from your `$books`.

So, we have to do the same thing. Figure out what category the user is asking, and then add that to your books query:

```
'cat' => get_query_var( 'cat' )
```

The function [get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) get's you exactly that. You can get whatever value WP would have used if it considered the uri and it's parameters. For brevity you can immediatly inject the above line in your `$args` array.

Comment: this (you make a category.php template in which you check the global $query in order to determine which sub category was asked and set the correct $args before generating the loop.)looks the best way to me too , but i have no clue how to do this , any help possible ?

Comment: Hi Nus , thnx for the clear explanation and this is working indeed ..... thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can get the categories of your CPT adding `'taxonomy' => 'category-declared-into-cpt',` to $args.

You have to add the taxonomy that have declared to create the CPT.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your query with **wp_reset_query();** and destroy your query codes.So, your code like this: **wp_reset_query(); while(have_posts()): // bla bla endwhile;**